# How to insert text to image by cv2.warpPerspective in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

Like this in python opencv:

```
i = 0
for line in wrapped_text:

    cv2.putText(img, line, (x, y), font,
                font_size, 
                (255,255,255), 
                font_thickness, 
                lineType = cv2.LINE_AA)
    i +=1

cv2.imshow("Result Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: Create an image of your text on transparent background. Then do a warpPerspective on it. Then overlay the text onto the background image.

Comment: use a perspective warp. calculate `H` using `getPerspectiveTransform`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Good question!
I think this way will work for your question.
First you will make a image from the text.
And then you can resize the image according to your mind. I think it's easy to resize the image.
And then you will compose the text image to the target image.

Comment: I am thinking like you.
But i don`t find the python functions on google.

Comment: Which step doesn't you understand on Python?

Comment: realtime text change on image...

Comment: I think it's possible to change the text as above steps.

Comment: Do you know python?
What is your main skill?

Comment: resizing to perspective part function.
Please check the puttext function again.

Comment: `@Marina Parshina` Do some research on your own. Search Google for examples of perspective warp.

Comment: So do you know the method?

Answer (score 0):

You don`t know the method.
But i have solved.